# Python: Import scrypt from subfolder to another subfolder

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-module

I am working on some python project (2.7) and I have issue with imports. When I run main.py it start scripts from tests folder etc. and save output to logs and everything works fine.

```
/root------------
        -logs
        -staticCfg
           -config.py
        -tests
           -systemTest
              -scrypt1.py
              -scrypt2.py
           -userTest
              -uScrypt1.py

main.py
```

My static variables (email, name etc.) are located in `config.py`. I need to import `config.py` in `scrypt1.py` or `scrypt2.py`. I tryed adding `__init__.py` to tests, systemTest and staticCfg folder but I always get an error.

In my `scrypt1.py`:

```
import staticCfg as cfg
...
```

or

```
from staticCfg import *
...
```

I get the error:

`ImportError: No module named staticCfg`

Comment: How do you run your tests and from where exactly ? What's the command you type in the terminal and where are you relative to root when you run it ? I assume you run it from within `tests` ?

Comment: I have main.py where I pass some arguments (python main.py -userTests) and that main.py is executing subprocess.Popen to run tests depending on arguments you entered

Answer (score 0):

The import mechanism of Python can be a bit tricky.

You can refer to the documentation for more information: [Python Import Mechanism](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

When you use absolute imports (your import does not start with a `.`) as you do, the import path will start from your main script (the one you launch). In your case, it's `scrypt1.py`. So starting from this location, python can't find the package `staticCfg`.

For me, the simplest solution is to create a main script in your root directory and call `scrypt1.py` from there (imported using `from tests.systemTet import scrypt1.py`). In this case, the base package will be your `root` folder and you will have access to the package `staticCfg` from all your script files as you wanted to do.

Answer (score -1):

you may add root folder to PYTHONPATH.

Comment: It's another way to resolve the problem but I consider this as a poor option because it makes the code way harder to read and understand.