# Python, import subfolder from another subfolder

Tags: python

When I try to access a sub-directory module from another sub-directory module it keep shows:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_1'
```

My current folders structure looks like this:

```
.
├── main.py (updated)
├── folder_1
│   ├── file1.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── folder_2
    ├── file2.py
    └── __init__.py
```

From `file1.py`:

```py
def abc():
   return True;
```

From `folder_1/__init__.py`

```py
from . import file1
```

From `folder2/file2.py`:

```py
from folder_1.file1 import abc
```

Is this the wrong way to access sub-folder module from another sub-folder?

Comment: I guess you need to check the documentation about [The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) and [Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: I came across this, is it not possible to import file1.py from file2.py and run file2.py? I tried adding a main.py at the root and run file2.py it works as mentioned in the link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076630/python-import-scrypt-from-subfolder-to-another-subfolder

Comment: Python (and possibly your IDE) needs to know that the folder that has `main.py` in it is a source root, so that it can find the `folder_1` module there.